# How to compute phases of the signals?

Tags: waves, terminology, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Let us take 4 signals which are sinusoidal and periodic. Suppose you are given a phase spectrum or (/and) equation of the (main) signal only and you are said that the given (main) signal is formed of 3 other  signals.

Is it possible to compute phases of these three signals from the equation or (/ and) phase spectrum of the (main) signal? Also,what information is contained in the phases of these signals?

**Note** : You can take any equation of your choice.

Comment: Could you give an equation? My thought is that this is possible if the signals have different frequencies (just find the Fourier coefficients at each frequency), but not if they are the same frequency (since then they all add into a single wave with a single phase you can't disentangle).

Comment: Do you mean complex as in "including real and imaginary components"? Or complex as in "messy"?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no you cannot.  If you're told that the three source signals are all sinusoidal (for example), then Fourier analysis will give you the answer.  But if, e.g., the three source signals are each a combination of various waveforms such as sawtooth or square, then there's no way to separate them unambiguously.

I would like to warn you that there's no difference between "sum" and "mix" when multiple signals are combined.  The complex amplitude at any point is the sum of all complex components at that point.

Edit: given that all signals are sinusoidal, just take the Fourier transform.  The real part will show peaks at each source wavelength/frequency and the imaginary part is used to calculated the relative phases among the signals.